# Make plotly always show the origin (0,0) when making the plot in R

Tags: r, plotly

I have a shiny application which present a scatterplot.  The shiny user perform data filtering, then the data is display in the plotly graph.  Sometime, the data created will be all negative or all positive, but I still want to plot to be positioned a way that the origin (0,0) is displayed.

Example:

```
dd <- data.frame(x=c(2,3,6,2), y=c(5,2,7,3))
plot_ly(data=dd, x=~x, y=~y, type="scatter", mode="markers")
```

gives:

[image]

But I want it to look initially more like that:

[image]

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use rangemode:

```
plot_ly(data=dd, x=~x, y=~y, type="scatter", mode="markers") %>%
  layout(
    xaxis = list(rangemode = "tozero"), 
    yaxis = list(rangemode = "tozero"))
```

[image]

This will also work with `dd2 <- -1 * dd`:

```
plot_ly(data=dd2, x=~x, y=~y, type="scatter", mode="markers") %>%
  layout(
    xaxis = list(rangemode = "tozero"), 
    yaxis = list(rangemode = "tozero"))
```

[image]

Comment: Both answer works, the one from @missuse is more flexible (you can make the plot larger) but this one is simpler.  I'll then chose this one for simplicity.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One can modify the axes ranges in layout like this:

```
plot_ly(data=dd, x=~x, y=~y, type="scatter", mode="markers") %>%
  layout(
      xaxis = list(range = c(~min(c(-1,x)), ~max(c(1,x)))),
      yaxis = list(range = c(~min(c(-1,y)), ~max(c(1,y)))))
```

[image]

Comment: It's a good start, but it as to work with `dd2 <- -1*dd` as well­. With `layout(
    xaxis = list(range = c(~min(c(-1,x)), ~max(c(1,x)))), 
    yaxis = list(range = c(~min(c(-1,y)), ~max(c(1,y)))))` it works, thanks